# Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, referenceerror

So I am new to JQuery and HTML and I got the `Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined` error in the console, but I don't know what that means or how to fix it.... My project should be a slide show so when you click on the next button it goes to the next picture. I haven't added in all of the photos yet because I wanted to get this working first, but there will be 4. Also, I'm use the editor on Khan Academy, so if some of the variables are weird (such as `var`) that's why.

Here is my body and script code and thanks for the help!

```
<body>

<br>
<img>
<button type="button" id="next">Next ➡</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> //access to jQuery library
<script>
var photo=function(nums){
    console.log("nums "+nums);//checking to see if the right number was received from the function
    if (nums===1){
        $("img")//I think the problem is here
            .css("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/mushroom.png")//photo on khan academy
            .css("width","400")
            .css("alt","Mushrooms");
    } else if (nums===2){
        $("img")
            .css("src","https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/food/coffee-beans.png") //photo on khan academy
            .css("width","400")
            .css("alt","Coffee Beans");
    }  
    $("img").slideDown(1000);
}

$("img").hide();

$("#next").on("click", function() {
        var num = 0;
        if(num < 4){
            num++;
        }else{
            num = 1;
        }
        console.log("num "+num);//checking to see if the right number was sent to the function
        photo(num);
    });


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: _"$(img)//I think the problem is here"_ Yup, you're missing the quotes around `img`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` needs to be a string

use `$("img")`

the way you have it written javascript is looking for an object called `img` which you never define.. alternatively you could define img like this `var img = "img"`

Answer (score 1):

Change`$(img)` to  `$("img")`. you missed `"` so browser is looking for `img object` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @mitchellm You are welcome. Good luck.